# Cron syntax what does # sign mean

Tags: cron

I am looking at the cron file in the /etc/cron.d, I am wondering what does the # sign in for one the jobs means:

`#50 23 * * *`

crontab.guru is not translating it

Answer (score 1):

The pound sign (**#**) is used to denote a comment in cron files. Anything after it is considered a comment and will be ignored.

You can temporarily disable that cron job by adding a pound sign in front of it, which is probably what you are seeing.